# How do you change file permissions on a minion in SaltStack?

Tags: linux, salt-stack

I need to change file permissions in Linux using SaltStack.

For a directory I can use the `file.directory` function, for example:

```
file.directory:
  - user: root
  - group: root
  - mode: 400
```

But what should I use for files?

I can use:

```
file.managed:
  - user: root
  - group: root
  - mode: 444
```

And it works, but I have a warning message:

> [WARNING ] State for file: /boot/grub/grub.cfg - Neither 'source' nor
> 'contents' nor 'contents_pillar' nor 'contents_grains' was defined,
> yet 'replace' was set to 'True'. As there is no source to replace the
> file with, 'replace' has been set to 'False' to avoid reading the file
> unnecessarily.

It expects a `source` directive, but I don't want to download the file to the minion, I just need to change file permissions.

The `file.exists` function doesn't have a `user`, `group` and `mode` directives.

What options do I have?

Comment: Could you post a code snippet from the file.managed state? The piece you have posted does not contain a filename and is therefore not complete. I hope I can help you.

Comment: Sure, this is a code snippet: 
/etc/cron.d:
  file.directory:
    - user: root
    - mode: 400
/boot/grub/grub.cfg:
  file.managed:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 400

Comment: Sorry for text formatting above. Code works fine, I only have a concerns about warnings in output. Maybe I use wrong function for my task?

Comment: I just checked it for you and it works on my machine. Next step to a solution could be to seperate this state to a new sls file and execute only this new state file with "salt minion state.apply new-file".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning message you get pretty much says it all. If you specify `replace: False` the message will be gone:

```
file.managed:
  - user: root
  - group: root
  - mode: 444
  - replace: False
```

Using `cmd.run` would obviously remove this message, but it's too generic and is more like a workaround here. The more *salty* approach would be to use `file.managed` state because this is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 3):

The state file.directory does set files' and/or directories' permissions recursively in just one state. Better than a cmd.run that will be executed even if nothing is changed (would play against the philosophy of 'states'). Note that file.managed is inadequate in this context.

```
otrs_enforce_perms:
  file.directory:
    - name: /opt/otrs
    - user: otrs
    - group: otrs
    - dir_mode: 770
    - file_mode: 660
    - follow_symlinks: True
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
```

If ignore_files or ignore_dirs is included under the recurse option, files or directories will be left unchanged respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not managed by salt you might want to use cmd.run instead and directly call the unix commands:

```
chown root:root /path/to/file:
  cmd.run

chmod 444 /path/to/file:
  cmd.run
```

Comment: Looks like it's the best option for me. Thank you!

Comment: This is not state-full, will run everytime.